# SessionState Expires before timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0

I have 2 session in my web application

here how i'm declaring my session:
Global.asax

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["login"] = "";
        Session["loginName"] = "Login";

    }
```

Web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="3600" /> <!--set the session timeout in minutes -->
```

sessions class:

```
    public class clsSession
{
    //declare sessions
    private static object cardCode;
    private static object cardName;       

    //get/set Login id session
    public static string LoginIdSession
    {
        get
        {
            cardCode = HttpContext.Current.Session["login"];
            return cardCode == null ? "" : (string)cardCode;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["login"] = value; 
        }
    }

    public static string LoginNameSession
    {
        get
        {
            cardName = HttpContext.Current.Session["loginName"];
            return cardName == null ? "Login" : (string)cardName; 
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["loginName"] = value;                 
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is the 2 sessions expire before timeout!

Thank you

Comment: "the 2 sessions expire before timeout" - how do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Well there could be lot of reasons for that. Some of them are:

- `Machine.Config`, `Web.Config` or `Global.asax` are modified
- The `bin` directory or its contents is modified
- The physical path of the virtual directory is modified
- There are few settings in `IIS` that can cause application pool or worker process to be recycled.
- If you have web farms setup, you need to use `Out-Proc` session state(StateServer or SQL Server)

Also check, IIS:

Right click on `application pool` -> `properties`

`Recycling Tab` -> "Recycle worker process (in minutes)" if this option is checked, make sure time set here should be the same as session timeout set in `web.config`.

`Performance Tab` -> "Shutdown worker processes after being ideal for" Make sure time set here should be the same as session timeout set in `web.config`

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'm working with windows server and there is no IIS role yet.
second thing, why should i change the mode? do you think 'InPorc' is not a good practice?

Comment: I said "If you have web farms setup, you need to use Out-Proc".

Comment: InProc means the session is stored in the memory space of the worker process and every time the worker process recycles all sessions will be lost.